# Setting multiple parameters in a request

Tags: java, spring, parameters, get, request

I need to form a cache, for regions by id, which are passed in the region_ids parameter, the request looks like this:

```
localhost:8080/cache/mscache?region_ids=5,19....,23
```

how is it best to read these several parameters in the program code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read them a String and the parse that String into whatever you want:

```
@GetMapping("/cache/mscache)
public String getCache(@RequestParam String listOfRegionIds)
    List<String> ids = Arrays.stream(listOfRegiosIds.split(",")).collect(Collectors.toList);
// ...
}
```

more info at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `array` or a `List`

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/test")
    public void test(@RequestParam List<String> ids) {
        ids.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Make a get request like:

`http://localhost:8080/test?ids=1,2,3`

Check [here](https://medium.com/@AADota/spring-passing-list-and-array-of-values-as-url-parameters-1ed9bbdf0cb2) for more details.

Comment: This answer is better than parsing the `region_ids`.

Comment: @NiceBooks I think the same too, better performance and less job to do :)

Answer (score 0):

If the request is a Get request use @RequestParam like sugessted by J Asgarov, if it is soething else you can also use @RequestBody by creating an class containing all of your parameters

for exemple a Post request could look like this :

```
@PostMapping("...")
public String postCache(@RequestBody RegionIdsRequest regionIds)
// ...
}

public class RegionIdsRequest{
    List<int> regionsIds = //...
}
```